# Popularisierung von „wir haben ein Problem“

Tags: history

Ich bin nicht ganz sicher, ob sich Daten für eine objektive Antwort werden finden lassen, aber da sich hier auch Germanisten tummeln, will ich es versuchen.

Meiner Familie ist ein eklatanter Anstieg in der Frequenz von „wir haben ein Problem“ zwischen 1950 und 2000 aufgefallen. Wir haben das dem Einfluss des Englischen zugeschrieben. Nun habe ich ein [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wir%20haben%20ein%20Problem&year_start=1900&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWir%20haben%20ein%20Problem%3B%2Cc0) erstellt und es fällt ein plötzlicher und kontinuierlicher Anstieg seit 1995 auf.

Dann habe ich gegoogelt und festgestellt, das „Houston, wir haben ein Problem“ im Film *[Apollo 13](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13_(film))* mit Tom Hanks aus dem Jahre 1995 vorkommt. Das könnte also passen. Aber reicht das als Erklärung wirklich aus? Man sieht keinen Peak oder eine Oszillation nach 1995. Warum blieb der Satz so ein Liebling?

Ich vermute, dass sich die These nicht verifizieren lässt. Falsifikation wäre aber möglich, falls gute Korpora ein aufkommen vor 1995 stützen.

Oder kann sich vielleicht jemand erinnern, dass „ein Problem haben” in seinem muttersprachlichen Umfeld vor 1995 oder sogar vor 1970 (Missionsjahr von Apollo 13) intensiv verwendet wurde?

[image]

Comment: Zunächst mal ist die Datenbasis (Textkorpus), auf der ngram beruht, recht zweifelhaft. Wenn man überhaupt eine Überlegung drauf stützen will, muss man sich erst mal bewusst machen, welche Texte dort eingehen und welche nicht. ich finde die These, dass solche Popularisierungen amerikanischer Redewendungen über Kinofilme etc. ins Deutsche kommen allerdings sehr plausibel. Wie nämlich sonst? - Interessanterweise könnte man dann sogar die schuldige Person identifizieren - irgend jemand muss ja die Dialoge ins Deutsche übersetzt haben.

Comment: Fänden sich zum Beispiel Daten, die einen Anstieg vor 1995 nahelegen, käme die These ins Wanken.

Comment: Schon beim Lesen der Überschrift dachte ich, ohne überhaupt grübeln zu müssen, sofort an "Houston, wir haben ein Problem." Auf mich trifft die Erklärung also hundertprozentig zu.

Comment: @Ludi  - Nicht unbedingt, solange die Auswahl der zugrundeliegenden ausgewerteten Texte nicht klar ist und sichergestellt ist, dass sie relevant ist und nichts Wichtiges auslässt. Vielleicht wurde "Wir haben ein Problem" auf Baustellen o. ä. ganz viel gesagt, aber es wurde nie geschrieben (oder jedenfalls nicht in Textsorten, die ngram zugänglich sind), und darum weiß ngram auch nichts davon? - Typisches Anwendungsfeld, das ngram entgehen würde: Beratungsgespräche beim Psychologen. Da kann die Wendung bei jedem Erstgespräch vorgekommen sein, und nie wurde sie öffentlich.

Comment: Darf ich aus diesem Anlass noch anmerken, dass "*Husten - Sie haben das Problem. Wir haben die Lösung"* ziemlich gut verwendbar wäre für eine Pharmafirma. (Ich beanspruche hiermit die Verwertungsrechte für diesen Slogan.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann stimmt. Vielleicht finden wir Nutzer in deren muttersprachlichem Umfeld das vor 1995 gern gesagt wurde?

Comment: @Ludi  Ich kenne einige Leute, die in der Zeit vor 1995 in psychologischen Beratungsdiensten tätig waren. Die könnte ich fragen, ob der Satz "Wir haben ein Problem" da regelmäßig vorkam. Das wäre natürlich nur annekdotische Evidenz, aber immerhin.

Comment: Ich finde die Frage ein bisschen sinnlos. Also ich hatte auch schon vor 1995 hin und wieder ein Problem (manchmal auch einen Unfall und öfters auch mal Schnupfen) und konnte das erstaunlicherweise auch ausdrücken, ohne auf einen US-amerikanischen Film zurückzugreifen.

Comment: @tofro   Die Antwort auf die Frage liegt vermutlich in der differenzierten Betrachtung von Nutzungszusammenhängen. Sicherlich wurde die Phrase "Ich habe ein Problem" im ganzen 20. Jahrhundert verwendet, aber eben beschränkt auf bestimmte Situationen im Privat- oder Arbeitsleben. Ich hab's nicht auf Tonband, aber ich hab's im Ohr, dass meine Bauernhofverwandschaft gerne sagte, wenn etwa der Traktor umfiel: "Jetz hemmer a Brobleem". Das war schon damals ironisch-sarkastisch, denn das Problem war ja offensichtlich. Und das schon in den 1970er und 1980er Jahren.

Comment: Noch eine Anmerkung zur ngram-Kurve: Ich weiß nicht, ob sie wirklich belegt, dass zwischen der steigenden Häufigkeit von Fundstellen von "Wir haben ein Problem" im Textkorpus und dem Film "Apollo 13" ein Zusammenhang besteht. Wieso steigt die Kurve nach 1995 dauernd an? Wäre nicht ein einmaliges starkes Ansteigen naheliegender, und dann z.B. eher horizontaler Verlauf der Kurve?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Für mündlichen Sprachgebrauch würde ich einen rascheren Anstieg erwarten, aber bis sich das in Büchern niederschlägt vergeht eben eine Weile. Und vom Film geht es ja auch in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch und bleibt da vielleicht und wandert von dort in weitere Bücher, nach und nach.

Answer (score 4):

Die Verwendung des englischen "We have a problem" scheint laut Google ngram keine ungewöhnliche Steigerung um das Filmjahr von Apollo 13 zu zeigen.

Jedoch ist es mehr als interessant auf das genaue ["Houston, we have a problem"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Houston,_we_have_a_problem)

> English
>   **Etymology**
>   The origin can be traced to the phrase in past tense (“Houston, we've had a problem here”) that was used by the crew of the Apollo 13 moon flight, to report a major technical problem back to their Houston base. **The phrase is normally misquoted as “Houston, we have a problem” as in the movie Apollo 13: “Houston, we have a problem”.**
>   See [Houston, We've Had a Problem (NASA)](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-350/ch-13-1.html).

[Mehr noch:](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/houston-we-have-a-problem.html)

> Swigert: 'Okay, Houston, we've had a problem here.'
>   Houston: 'This is Houston. Say again please.'
>   Lovell: 'Houston, we've had a problem. We've had a main B bus undervolt.'
>
> 'Houston, we have a problem' was used later as the tagline for the 1995 film - Apollo 13. It is the dialogue of the film. edited for dramatic effect, that is now best remembered:
>   Uh, this is Houston. Uh, say again, please? 
>   Houston, we have a problem. We have a main bus B undervolt.
>   **The issue of the film brought about a renewal in the use of the line and, from then onwards, it began being used in non-spaceflight contexts.** The first example of such that I can find is as the title of a none too favourable review in the Los Angles Times, July 1995, of a restaurant called Houstons:
>
> > Houston('s), we have a problem - Houston's is yet another slick corporate package, the antithesis of a mom-and-pop restaurant.

Die Popularisierung durch den Film kann als äußerst wahrscheinlich angesehen werden. Der Film selbst, die Werbung dazu, mit dem Falschzitat auf den Plakaten sprechen dafür. Ebenfalls die immer noch anhaltende Verwendung des falschen Zitats aus dem Film für das reale Ereignis:

> [Spiegel, 2011: Raumfahrt-Zitate: "Wir haben ein Problem"](http://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/raumfahrt-zitate-wir-haben-ein-problem-fotostrecke-66348-5.html)
>   "Houston, wir haben ein Problem."
>   "Apollo-13"-Astronaut John Swigert am 13. April 1970 an das Nasa-Kontrollzentrum nach der Explosion eines Sauerstofftanks

Diese Verwendung zieht sich [bis in jüngste Zeit durch, mit kleineren Korrekturen:](http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/weltall/klingeltoene-nasa-veroeffentlicht-shuttle-sprueche-fuers-handy-a-1019170.html)

> Der Spruch zählt wohl zu den Untertreibungen des Jahrhunderts. Als die Besatzung der Apollo 13 im Jahr 1970 auf dem Weg zum Mond "Houston, wir haben ein Problem" Richtung Erde funkte, war nicht sicher, ob sie lebend zurückkehren würde. Ein Sauerstofftank war explodiert, die Mission musste sofort abgebrochen werden, der Rückflug wurde improvisiert.
>
> Spätestens seit dem Film "Apollo 13" ist "Houston, we have a problem" eine gängige Redewendung. Die im Film von Tom Hanks gebrauchten Worte entsprechen allerdings nicht exakt dem Original "Houston, we've had a problem" (Wir hatten ein Problem).

Sofern Zeitungsarchive öffentlich durchsuchbar sind gibt es auf Zeit zB keine Ergebnisse vor 1995, auf Spiegel eine Eintrag von [Raumfahrt Apollo 13: Die Längste Nacht - Der Spiegel 17/1970](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-44944170.html) mit leichter Verfälschung.

Durch den Film wurde ein gewöhnlicher Satz in eine Redewendung, eine stehende Phrase überführt.

Die reine Wortkombination "…wir haben ein Problem…" ist natürlich auch vor der Filmveröffentlichung zu finden.

> [image] [image]  DWDS-Wortverlaufskurven für „Wir haben ein Problem“

Als ganzer Satz ist das aber eigentlich eine Ellipse. "Was denn für ein Problem?" wird man sich fragen. Zuvor war es unüblich, den Satz nach "Problem" einfach zu beenden. 
In der dokumentierten Verwendung scheint meist ein Komma oder ein "mit …" danach zu stehen. [Beispiel](https://www.google.com/search?q=wir%20%22ein%20problem%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1500,cd_max:1994). Selbst in Situationen, die schon fast als direkte Zitate des Films zu lesen wären "[Wir haben ein Problem mit dem Warpantrieb](http://www.ussmirage.de/Spiel/Miss_M03/kap01.php)." oder als Quellen ("[Captain, wir haben ein Problem mit dem Warpkern, oder mit den Phaseninduktoren, oder mit einem anderen verdammten Ding.](http://de.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gestern,_Heute,_Morgen,_Teil_I)")

Als Phrase ist dies *in* einem Satz also oft zu finden. Als ganzen Satz, erst mit den Bildern im Kopf, die jetzt überall in den Lexika stehen: plötzlich, unvorhergesehene Schwierigkeiten von [größter Bedeutung](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/31372-Houston_wir_haben_ein_Problem) oder eben [humorvoll](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/houston-we-have-a-problem) gewendet, lakonisch als [*understatement*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Understatement) oder [*wham-line*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhamLine).

Comment: Ich versuche noch zu verstehen, was man mit einem Problem sehr viel anderes machen könnte, als es zu "haben" und wieso man einen Film dazu brauchen könnte.

Comment: @tofro  Die Frage der Verwendung des Worts "Problem" in verschiedenen Kontexten und Lebensituationen ist komplizierter als man vielleicht zunächst denkt. Zum Beispiel wird das Wort in bestimmten Wissenschaftszusammenhängen eben nicht verstanden als "unerwünschte Erschwernis, die aber vielleicht beseitigt werden kann" (wie wir es im Alltag gerne verwenden) sondern als "Fragestellung".

Comment: @tofro Probleme könnte man auch lösen… Ernsthaft: Der Satz ist eigentlich eine Ellipse. "Was denn für ein Problem?" Zuvor war es unüblich, den Satz nach Problem einfach zu beenden. Google und du wirst meistenes ein Komma danach finden. Als Phrase *in* einem Satz oft zu finden. Als ganzen Satz, erst mit den Bildern im Kopf, die jetzt überall in den Lexika stehen: plötzlich, unvorhergsehene Schwierigkeiten von größter Bedeutung.

Comment: Schöne Antwort. Nur eins: Die Behauptung am Anfang, dass die Leute heute mehr Probleme hätten als früher, ist natürlich entweder Blödsinn, Leichtsinn oder Ironie. Wie sollte man es messen? Kommen Probleme als diskrete Einheiten daher? Wenn ja: Hatten die Leute im Mittelalter nicht mehr Probleme als wir heute? Keine Waschmaschine; ein Gewimmel von Heiligen, die bedient werden wollten; immer wieder eine Hungersnot; übergriffige Adlige und andere Brutalos... oder muss man es aufrechnen gegen Probleme, die sie nicht hatten, z.B. Dieselabgase... dafür den Qualm in der schornsteinlosen Hütte...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ja, zynische Ironie. Kam mir bei der Betrachtung der englischen NGramme in den Sinn. Und dazu noch unpräzise da in den späten 90ern dann doch ein Buckel zu sehen war… ich streich das gerade.

Comment: @LangLangC  Lass es stehen. Es ist ja jetzt zu  genüge diskutiert und aufgeklärt. Kleine Stolpersteine zum Aufsatzeinstieg sind immer nett.

Comment: Ich höre in der letzten Zeit immer öfter: "Ja, ist auch wichtig". Kommt wohl aus der Fernsehserie "Mord mit Aussicht". Natürlich wurde das auch schon früher gesagt, aber es scheint sich in dieser Form zu häufen (wenigstens hier).

Comment: @tofro meiner Meinung nach sagte man vorher *es besteht ein Problem*. Allerdings verwendete man es  im Alltag nicht so oft wie heute, sondern eher *Schwierigkeiten, Ärger*... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Es+besteht+ein+Problem%2Cwir+haben+ein+Problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEs%20besteht%20ein%20Problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwir%20haben%20ein%20Problem%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Ludi Und meiner Meinung nach bist du da auf dem Holzweg. Was ihr hier herumphilosophiert, bewegt sich auf sehr dünnem Eis, wie so vieles, was sich auf ngrams als Argumentationshilfe stützt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ist+&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cist%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bist%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIst%3B%2Cc0 Nach diesem Diagramm ist die Verwendung des Wortes "ist" seit den 50-er Jahren stark zurückgegangen. Befindet sich deshalb die existentielle Welt in Auflösung?

Comment: @tofro guter Einwand. Wir haben ja schon festgestellt, daß ngram nicht zu trauen sei. Allerdings deckt sich das späte Aufkommen des Satzes mit meiner subjektiven Erinnerung. Ich akzeptiere sehr gern Antworten mit Gegenbeispielen! Die Frage entspringt ja gerade dem Zweifel an diesem ersten Erklärungsansatz!

Comment: +1 für die Unterscheidung abgeschlossener Satz/Phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Um die Debatte auf eine leeeeicht solidere Datenbasis zu stellen, hier einmal die Kurve, die DWDS uns gibt basierend auf einem immerhin eeeetwas klareren Textkorpus, nämlich Zeitungstexten seit 1945:

[image]

Der intessierte Laie lernt daraus, dass die Formulierung "Wir haben ein Problem" bei den im Textkorpus figurierenden Zeitungstexten seit ca 1967 auftritt.<sup>1</sup> Das ist ja schon mal interessant.

Außerdem könnte man zum Schluss kommen, dass der steile Anstieg in den 1990er Jahren schon vor 1995 einsetzte. Jedenfalls in Zeitungen.

Den Knick nach unten von 2010 auf 2011 brauchen wir nicht ernst zu nehmen: es sind 104 gegen 102 Fundstellen - das ist natürlich im Rahmen einer normalen Zufallsschwankung.

Hier noch der Blick auf die Rohdatenkurve (nicht normalisiert). Der sagt uns auch noch was...

[image]

... nämlich: Da ist in der Tat ein hübscher Sprung im Jahre 1995 mit 40 Treffern im Gegensatz zu 12 im Vorjahr. Dies nun dürfte wirklich auf den Film "Apollo 13" zurückgehen. (Die waagrechten grauen Linien markieren hier jeweils 20 Treffer.)

---

<sup>1)</sup> Die erste Zählung konkreter Vorkommen ist für 1970 mit 4 angegeben. Die Jahre davor, die auf der Kurve ja einen Anstieg zeigen, sind in den Datenpunkte mit "absolut: 0" markiert. Diese Kurve zeigt eine *normalisierte* Frequenz (also mit Ausstrahlungen von Daten auf ihre Nachbarzeitpunkte.) Interessant finde ich, dass "Wir haben ein Problem" 1970 gleich viermal gefunden wurde.

Comment: Und 1970 war die Odyssey nicht auf dem Mond. Sie hatte da so ein Problem… Einen der Treffer hab ich da als link.